# Call to a member function compileColumnListing() on null

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am getting **Call to a member function compileColumnListing() on null** error message.
Following is my line of code in **Laravel**.

```
$lodesUpdate = new Lode();
$lodesUpdate->where('_id', $data->id)->first()->update(['status' => "0", 'win_amount' => $totalWiningAmount]);
```

Could anyone please help me to short it out.

Thanks.

Comment: Where is the method ‘compileColumnListing’? $lodesUpdate is null I expect.

Comment: May be you want something like `$lodesUpdate = Lode::where('_id', $data->id)->update(['status' => "0", 'win_amount' => $totalWiningAmount]);`